# Solving Linear Inequalities Over Integers

Tags: inequality, integers

The inequalities I want to solve are: $120n - 120m \leq 119$ and $120m - 120n \leq -41$. I want to find the integer values of $m$ and $n$.

I try to use Cuts-from-Proofs algorithm in *Dillig, Isil; Dillig, Thomas; Aiken, Alex*, [**Cuts from proofs: a complete and practical technique for solving linear inequalities over integers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-02658-4_20), Bouajjani, Ahmed (ed.), et al., Computer-aided verification. 21st international conference, CAV 2009, Grenoble, France, June 26–July 2, 2009. Proceedings. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-02657-7/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 5643, 233-247 (2009). [ZBL1242.65116](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.65116).

However, I still can not solve it. Are there any solutions?

*Hint*: In my problem, I only can change the value of the right-hand side (RHS) of the inequalities, i.e., $119$ and $-41$.
For example, if I add one to the RHS, the inequalities become $120n - 120m \leq 120$ and $120m - 120n \leq -40$. I can obtain the integer values of $m$ and $n$. But, how can I prove it to show that it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are no solutions to the given system in integers $m$ and $n$.

From $120m - 120n \leq -41$, obtain $120n - 120m \geq 41$.  Combining with the first given inequality, we have
$$  41 \leq 120n - 120m \leq 119  \text{.}  $$
Notice that $120 n - 120m = 120(n-m)$, which is the product of $120$ and some integer, $n-m$, so is a multiple of $120$.  There are no multiples of $120$ between $0 \cdot 120 = 0$ and $1 \cdot 120$ = 120, so there are none in the interval $[41,119]$.  Therefore, there are no integer solutions to the given inequalities.

Generalizing by varying the right hand sides, perform the same manipulations.  From
$$  \begin{cases}
120 n - 120 m \leq a  \\
120 m - 120 n \leq b
\end{cases}  \text{,}  $$
obtain from the second, $120n - 120 m \geq -b$, so that you have
$$  -b \leq 120n -120 m \leq a  \text{.}  $$
Then, if there is no multiple of $120$ in $[-b,a]$, there is no solution.  Otherwise, every multiple of $120$ in that interval as obtained by infinitely many choices of $m$ and $n$.

(Suppose $120$ is in that interval, then for every integer $c$, $m = c+1$ and $n = c$ gives $120n - 120m = 120$.  So each integer $c$ gives a different solution.)

Comment: Any ideas to change the inequalities so it can have integer solutions of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @gu0hu1 : Did you read **any** of the material in the Answer after "Generalizing by varying the right hand sides" which describes the conditions on $a$ and $b$ necessary for solutions to exist, at which point infinitely many solutions exist.